# HQL Map with relationships

Tags: hibernate, coldfusion, hql, coldfusion-10

I have a hierarchy model where I am trying to build a collection of Businesses with their associated Centers (one-to-many). The following in the HQL I am using:

```
SELECT new map(b.businessName as name, c as centers) FROM Business b JOIN b.centers c GROUP BY c.centerID
```

My expected result is (using JSON for reference):

```
[
  {"name": "Business 1",
   "centers": [ centerEntity1, centerEntity2, centerEntity... ]
  },
  {"name": "Business 2",
   "centers": [ centerEntity3, centerEntity4, centerEntity... ]
  }
]
```

However, I seem to be getting results in more of a one-to-one relation:

```
[
  {"name": "Business 1",
   "centers": centerEntity1
  },
  {"name": "Business 2",
   "centers": centerEntity2
  }
]
```

On top of this, it's running 1 query to get the Business details, and then additional queries to get all the Centers. I would assume this would all be combined into 1 query using JOIN FETCH, but that produces an error:

*query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=c,role=Business.centers,tableName=vw_hier_centers,tableAlias=centers1_,origin=vw_hier_businesses business0_,columns={business0_.business_id ,className=Center}}] [select new map(b.businessName as name, c as centers) FROM Business b JOIN FETCH b.centers c GROUP BY c.centerID]*

Answer (score 2):

The thought behind this was far too complicated. Here's the solution that fit exactly what I needed:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b FROM Business b JOIN FETCH b.centers
```

1 query, and it gets an array of Businesses with their fetched Centers.